$SO^3$ is topologically equivalent to a projective 3-space $P^3$
I am currently reading Steenrod's Topology of fibre bundles. In page 115, it states that the special orthogonal group $SO_3$ is isomorphic to a projective 3-space $P^3$. The proof that is given uses the map $\rho: S^3 \longrightarrow SO_3$ defined by $\rho(z) \cdot z'= zz'z^{-1}$, where $z'$ is in $S^2$. $S^3$ is considered here as the quaternionic subgroup of numbers with an absolute value of $1$, and $S^2$ as the subset of $S^3$ with scalar part $0$. How exactly does the map given work? Is $z'$ just an arbitrary element of $S^2$? Is Steenrod saying that to each $z \in S^3$ it corresponds an aplication $\rho_z: z' \longrightarrow zz'z^{-1}$, where $z' \in S^2$? I am supposing that $\cdot$ refers to quaternionic multiplication and when we don't use it, the operation is matrix multiplication and the elements are regarded as matrices.

Suggest writing it out incoordinates, a unit quaternion being $z=a + bi + cj + dk$   so that $z^{-1} = a - bi - cj - dk.$ Then $z' = ei + fj + gk.$ Note that $z^{-1} = \bar z,$   also $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 1,$  The outcome of $z z' \bar z$  is a linear combination of $i,j,k$  as the real part comes out zero. Also, and this is the punchline, the mapping given by $z$  is the same as the mapping given by $-z ; ; ; ;$  that is where the projective part comes from. Usual ly stated as a "double cover"

For an elementary argument see  The Spinor Spanner, https://www.jstor.org/stable/2318771

There's a very geometric way to visualize the homeomorphism $\mathbb{RP}^3 \cong \operatorname{SO}(3)$. I have to think some more about whether its equivalent to the homeomorphism you describe via quaternionic conjugation.
First consider the model of $\mathbb{RP}^3$ as the $D^3/\sim$ where antipodal points on the boundary of the ball are identified. A rotation in $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ is (almost) uniquely characterized by a radial direction that acts as an oriented axis (equivalently, a unit vector $\mathbf{u} \in S^2$) and real number in $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ describing angle of rotation. There are two caveats:

Identity rotation $\theta = 0$ so $\mathbf{u}$ is not well-defined: i.e., $(\mathbf{u}, 0) \sim (\mathbf{u}', 0)$ for any $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{u}' \in S^2$.
When rotating by exactly half a turn, there are two descriptions since it doesn't matter whether it's clockwise or counterclockwise: i.e., $(\mathbf{u}, \pi) \sim (-\mathbf{u}, \pi)$

Now think of $D^3$ as an onion, concentric spheres of radii from $0$ to $1$. So every point is a pair $(\mathbf{u}, r)$, where $\mathbf{u} \in S^2$ and $r \in [0, 1]$, with the one catch that $(\mathbf{u}, 0) \sim (\mathbf{u}', 0)$ for any $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{u}' \in S^2$, i.e.,
$$
D^3 \cong (S^2 \times [0, 1]) \,/ \sim
$$
Can you make this homeomorphism explicit?
There's a nice map from $D^3 \to \operatorname{SO}(3)$ that respects both of these issues:
$$
(\mathbf{u}, r) \mapsto (\mathbf{u}, \pi r)
$$
It remains to check that this map is

Well-defined
Surjective
Injective on the interior of the ball and $2$-to-$1$ on the boundary.
Continuous

Then it descends to a continuous map $\mathbb{RP}^3 \to \operatorname{SO}(3)$. We can then construct a continuous inverse, establishing the homeomorphism.

$\cdot$ does not refer to quaternion multlplication. It is the action of $SO_3$ on a vector. We're essentially treating $S^2$ as the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ and acting on it with $SO_3$ as you usually would, via rotations.
So the claim is that $z' \mapsto zz'z^{-1}$ is a rotation of $z'$, hence $\rho(z) = (z' \mapsto zz'z^{-1})$ is an element of $SO_3$.

The quaternions can be realised as
$$
Q=\left\{A(z,w)=\begin{bmatrix} z & -\bar{w} \\ w & \bar{z} \end{bmatrix}: z,w \in \mathbb C\right\}
$$
where the standard basis $\{1,i,j,k\}$ of the quaternions corresponds to $\{A(1,0),A(i,0),A(0,1),A(0,i)\}$.
It is easy to see that the quaternionic conjugation is given in this realisation by $A\mapsto A^*:= \bar{A}^{\intercal}$, and hence the norm is given by
$$
N(A) = A^*A = (|z|^2+|w|^2)I_2=\det(A).I_2
$$
(note that if $A \in Q$ then $A^*$ is the adjugate of $A$).
The unit quaternions are therefore
$$
\mathbb U = \left\{ A=\begin{bmatrix} z & -\bar{w} \\ w & \bar{z}\end{bmatrix}: |z|^2+|w|^2=1\right\} 
$$
and it is straightforward to check that the right-hand side of the above is precisely $\mathrm{SU}_2 = \{A \in \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb C): AA^*=I_2, \det(A)=1\}$ (and clearly $\mathbb U$ is $3$-sphere).
Now if
$$
\mathbb I = \{A \in Q: \text{tr}(A) =2\Re(z)=0\} = \{A\in Q: A^*=-A\},
$$
then clearly $\mathbb U$ acts on $I$ by conjugation, and that action moreover preserves the restriction of the norm $N$ to $\mathbb I$, so that this conjugation action gives a group homomorphism from $c\colon\mathrm{SU}_2 \to \mathrm{SO}(\mathbb I) \cong \mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb R)$, where $c(A)(J) = AJA^{-1} = AJA^*$. Since the centre of $\mathrm{SU}_2$ is precisely $\{\pm I_2\}$ it follows that the image of $c$ is obtained by identifying antipodal points on $\mathbb U$, that is, the image of $c$ is $\mathbb RP^3$. It follows that $\mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb R)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb RP^3$ if we show that $c$ is surjective.
There are many ways to show surjectivity: for example, the derivative of the map $c$ at the identity can be checked to be an isomorphism from $\mathfrak{su}_2$ to $\mathfrak{so}_3$ (e.g. both are simple real Lie algebras and the map is nonzero, hence it must be an isomorphism). But then the map $c$ has invertible derivative everywhere, and hence is an open map. But since $\mathrm{SU}_2$ is compact, its image must therefore be open and closed, and hence as $\mathrm{SO}_3$ is connected, $c$ must be surjective.
A more hands-on approach is directly verify that the image of $c$ contains all rotational symmetries on $\mathbb I$. For this, note that if $J \in \mathbb I$ is a unit quaternion, $J^*=J^{-1}=-J$ hence $J^2=-I_2$. Then one can check that $S_J:=\{\cos(\theta)I_2+\sin(\theta)J: \theta\in \mathbb R\}$ is the stabilizer of $J$ in $\mathbb U$, and $c(S_J)$ is the group of rotations about the axis given by $J$.
Steenrod writes $\rho(z)\cdot$ to denote the orthogonal transformation
given by the conjugation action of the quaternions on the purely imaginary quaternions (which I have denoted by $\mathbb I$) that is, he write $c(A)(J) = AJA^{-1}$ as $\rho(A)\cdot J$, or rather, as he uses $z$ and $z'$ instead of $A$ and $J$, once you check that $z'\mapsto zz'z^{-1}$ is an isometry of $\mathbb I$ it follows that it is given by an element of $\mathrm{SO}_3$ which Steenrod denotes by $\rho(z)$.
Note that Steenrod seems to only consider the action of $\mathrm{SU}_2$ on the unit sphere in $\mathbb I$, and of course a linear isometry is determined by its action on the unit sphere, but the map $z' \mapsto zz'z^{-1}$ defines a linear map on all of $\mathbb I$, so there is no particular need to restrict to $S^2$.
It may also be worth noting that $Q = \mathbb R.I_2 \oplus \mathbb I$, and the conjugation action of $\mathbb U$ on $Q$ of course acts trivially on $\mathbb R.I_2$, thus by restricting the conjugation action to $\mathbb I$ does not lose any nontrivial information about the conjugation action of $\mathbb U$.

Wikipedia describes the double covering in the following:
$$Spin_3=Pin_3\cap Cl^{even}_{3,0}$$
$$p: Pin_3\to O_2$$
$$p: Spin_3\to SO_3$$
$$p(\alpha).v=\alpha v\alpha^*$$
where $v\in \Bbb R^3=\text{Span}(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ and $*$ is the anti automorphism so that $1^*=1$, $e_{i}^*=-e_i$, $(e_ie_j)^*=e_je_i$.
For all $i$, it turns out that,  $p(e_i)\in O(3)$ is the reflection in the hyperplane perpendicular to $e_i$, $p(\alpha)$ is a rotation when $\alpha\in Spin_3\cong S^3\subset\Bbb H$. Furthermore, it turns out that $p$ is a $2:1$ covering map with $p(-\alpha)=p(\alpha)$. Here, $V$ is not realized as a subset of $\Bbb H.$
